# Google oauth 2.0 sign in vs firebase auth sign in. What is the difference?

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, google-authentication

I generally use the OAUTH flow for logging users to my personal website. A friend recommended firebase authentication to me. What is the difference between the two and pros and cons of each?

Comment: A Google search gives some promising results: https://www.google.com/search?q=Google+oauth+2.0+sign+in+vs+firebase+auth+sign+in.+What+is+the+difference%3F. Did you check some of those out yet?

Comment: @frank did not find any that cleared my doubts